# Counting the drop down value using selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

i got stuck in a situation where i have different drop down for different city and i want to count the number of value in each city for eg for london uk drop down there is an airport (CHild)drop down when i select the airport drop  it will populate all the airport available in london so i want to count the number of air port

Thanks in  advance

Comment: By using Selenium IDE you cannot do counting, for your problem you have to use selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting `London` all you need to do is a `len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.child option'))`, where `.child` is the css class of your child select object.

`find_elements` returns an array, and `len()` just counts it (in python).